# transferring Secure data between web server and app

Tags: android, webserver, data-transfer

i want transfer data between web server and app,data is strings and Numbers.i can use XML files,but it not secure.what is secure way for it?

Comment: encrypt your data before transferring and decrypt it on receiving.. you can try mcrypt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the CipherStreams. They are built in encrypted streams which allow you to securely send data between devices

[CipherOutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/CipherOutputStream.html)

Hope this is applicable for you ;)